# Mean absolute percentage error (MAPE) in Scikit-learn

Tags: predictive-models, python, scikit-learn, mape

How can we calculate the Mean absolute percentage error (MAPE) of our predictions using Python and scikit-learn?

From [the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#regression-metrics), we have only these 4 metric functions for Regressions:

- metrics.explained_variance_score(y_true, y_pred)
- metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred)
- metrics.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)
- metrics.r2_score(y_true, y_pred)

Comment: Refer this answer on stackOverflow- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42250958/how-to-optimize-mape-code-in-python

Comment: It is available in scikit-learn from version 0.24 onwards ([see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71212194/7109869)).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As noted (for example, [in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_percentage_error)), MAPE can be problematic. Most pointedly, it can cause division-by-zero errors. My guess is that this is why it is not included in the sklearn metrics.

However, it is simple to implement.

```
from sklearn.utils import check_arrays
def mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred): 
    y_true, y_pred = check_arrays(y_true, y_pred)

    ## Note: does not handle mix 1d representation
    #if _is_1d(y_true): 
    #    y_true, y_pred = _check_1d_array(y_true, y_pred)

    return np.mean(np.abs((y_true - y_pred) / y_true)) * 100
```

Use like any other metric...:

```
> y_true = [3, -0.5, 2, 7]; y_pred = [2.5, -0.3, 2, 8]
> mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred)
Out[19]: 17.738095238095237
```

(Note that I'm multiplying by 100 and returning a percentage.)

... but with caution:

```
> y_true = [3, 0.0, 2, 7]; y_pred = [2.5, -0.3, 2, 8]
> #Note the zero in y_pred
> mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred)
-c:8: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide
Out[21]: inf
```

Comment: There's an error in this answer. Should be (replace `y_pred` with `y_true` in denominator): `return np.mean(np.abs((y_true - y_pred) / y_true)) * 100`

Comment: `check_arrays` was ditched by scipy. There's `check_array` in the current sklearn but it doesn't seem like it works the same way.

Comment: check_arrays method is removed from .16.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42250958/how-to-optimize-mape-code-in-python

Answer (score 37):

here is an updated version:

```
import numpy as np

def mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred): 
    y_true, y_pred = np.array(y_true), np.array(y_pred)
    return np.mean(np.abs((y_true - y_pred) / y_true)) * 100
```

Comment: What if one of y_true is 'zero' ? Divide by zero error ?

Comment: Add a very small number to the denominator to avoid infinity

Comment: @JackDaniel isn't this going to overly penalise the model? imagine the real value is 0 and the predicted 2 (in many contexts that would be good prediction). but if you divide 2 by a very small number you will get a huge error estimate

Comment: @LetsPlayYahtzee Yeah, agreed. I did face the issue. I moved to MAAPE Error instead of MAPE.